# Parse push notification with ionic on ios 9.2

Tags: ios, push-notification, ionic-framework

I am trying to setup parse push notifications on ionic created iOS app. I can see the device token being generated in the xCode console and also see that it say "Ionic Push: (debug) device token registered:", but I can't see any registered device in parse installation.
The code inside the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not being called and the console lists an error - "Unexpected call to didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken".

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

---UPDATE---

Code being used in AppDelegate.m file in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:-

`UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |                       UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes                                                             categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];`

Comment: Did you call application.registerForRemoteNotifications()?

Comment: @CaileanW: I did put the code for registering remote notifications in my xCode in AppDelegate.m file. I have updated my question with the code.